# Magento2.2.4: breadcrumbs disappeared from product page

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs, magento2.2.4

I have a website developed with Magento 2.2.4.

There is a problem with breadcrumbs.

Breadcrumbs are showing on all the pages except Product page.

How can i check what's error ?!

Comment: Please check from code breadcrumbs are removed from xml for product page?

Comment: I have checked that. actually the div with class breadcrumbs is exists, but the data is not there. div is empty at all!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check committed code in breadcrumb.js in below URL. it will solve your issue.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/34a871bad70e60b1277a28481fc597c79101ad90

Comment: I confirm the presence of this bug on Magento 2.2.4; Editing breadcrumbs.js located at vendor/magento/magento-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js did solve the issue.

Comment: However, now breadcrumbs on product view pages don't show category paths, which renders them somewhat useless to display on the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Search a code like `<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>` in a `catalog_product_view.xml` file in front-end view.

OR

Do a view source and press `ctrl+F` and search text `breadcrumbs`, it may be hidden behind the header menu.